# Hidden field value is lost

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to read the text in the textbox and assign the hidden text field in a form. When I check the value with alert, everything looks good, but when I send it to my server on, I only have value in the first hidden field

The textbox is 2640 characters but i can only send fields with 256 characters

I'm pretty new at this and would really need help to understand why only the first hidden field get value

Thanks

*** Submitting the form**

```
function SendForm(){
    with(document.TUrgF){
        alert($('#F1').val()); 
        alert($('#F2').val()); 
        submit();
    }
}
```

*** Loading textbox wiht values from database**

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#TextBox1').append('/(TEXT1)');
    $('#TextBox1').append('/(TEXT2)');
    $('#TextBox1').append('/(TEXT3)');
});
```

*** The Form**

```
<FORM ACTION="xxxxx" NAME="TUrgF" METHOD="POST" AUTOCOMPLETE="OFF">
    <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="TEXT1" ID="F1" value="/(FULLTEXT1)">
    <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="TEXT2" ID="F2" value="/(FULLTEXT2)">
    <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="TEXT3" ID="F3" VALUE="/(FULLTEXT3)">
</FORM>
```

*** Textarea:**

```
<textarea id="TextBox1" cols="110" rows="24"></textarea>
```

*** Extract data from  textbox**

```
$("#getData").click(function() {
    var data = $("#TextBox1").val();
    var str = data;
    var a = 0;
    var b = 240;
    for (var i = 0, limit = 10; i < limit; i++) {
        var res = (str.substring(a,b));
        a = b;
        b = b + 240;
        if (i == 0) {
            $('#F1').val(res);
        }   
        if (i == 1) {
            $('#F2').val(res);
        }
        if (i == 2) {
            $('#F3').val(res);
        }
        if (i == 3) {
            $('#F4').val(res);
        }
    }   
    SendForm();
});
```

Comment: when inserting values into the textbox you want to use `.val` instead of `.append`, also you overwrite `#Textbox1` or is this just copy and paste error

Comment: Is the textarea in the form?

Comment: Are you sure you need to do this when submitting the textarea within the form will produce the same result? (As far as I can tell). You can always hide the textarea if you need to.

Comment: No, the textarea is ot in the form. The thing is that wh have to let the users write a lot og text (2640 char) but i can only send 256 long fields. So my solution was, probably wrong, but to send 11 fields with length of 240 char